# Como salvar/recuperar imagem na memória no android?

Tags: java, android

Olá, tenho um **Array de Bytes** que é  uma **imagem**, apartir dele, como posso salvar na **memória externa** e caso não exista salvar na **memória interna** do android? e depois como posso estar recuperando essa imagem?

Preciso salvar em um local que essas imagens não apareçam na galeria do celular, somente na aplicação.

Comment: Crie uma tabela no banco de dados sqlite e salve o array de bytes como um objeto Blob. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Blob.html

Comment: Mas é isso que estou fazendo no momento, mas as imagens com um tamanho de 2MB estão dando erro na hora de fazer a leitura. Acho que se eu persistir no BD imagens com esse tamanho pode ficar mt pesado o sqlite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos primeiro escrever um método que verifique a existência do *SDCard* e se é possível escrever nele:

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

O método retorna *true* se é possível escrever no *SDCard* ou *false* caso não exista ou por qualquer razão não é possível escrever nele.

Necessitamos de dois métodos para salvar o *byte[]*, um para salvar na memória interna e outro para salvar no *SDCard*.

**Salvar na memória interna:**

```
public void saveArrayToInternalStorage(String fileName, byte[] imagem){
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(imagem);
        fos.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("InternalStorage", "Error writing", e);
    }
}
```

**Salvar no SDCard:**

Para que o *MediaStore* não veja as imagens usaremos [`getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) para obter o *Path* ao SDCard.

```
public void saveArrayToSDCard(String fileName, bytes[] imagem){
    File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File file = new File(path, fileName);
    try{
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        os.write(imagem);
        os.close()
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing", e);
    }
}
```

**Como usar:**

```
if(isExternalStorageWritable(){
   saveArrayToSDCard("nomeDaImagem", imagemEmBytes);
}else{
    saveArrayToInternalStorage("nomeDaImagem", imagemEmBytes);
}
```

Se a aplicação for para correr em versões anteriores ao Android 4.4, é neccessário obter a permissão **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**, adicione o seguinte ao *Manifest*

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

***Nota:*** As imagens gravadas por estes métodos serão apagadas quando a aplicação for desinstalada.

Fonte: [Android Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado, amanhã testarei essa solução. e referente a nota "As imagens gravadas por estes métodos serão apagadas quando a aplicação for desinstalada. " é um grande alivio, pois as imagens que estou trabalhando são um tanto "pesadas".

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu li [nesse tópico do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300407/access-large-blob-in-android-sqlite-without-cursor) o limite é 1 MB, mais do que isso você teria que utilizar o NDK.

Nesse mesmo tópico também existe outra abordagem que utiliza o *sqlite4java*.

Dê uma olhada, pode ser útil.

Comment: Muito bom saber que o erro ocorre pois ultrapassou o limite estabelecido, fiquei preocupado inicialmente achando que fosse algum erro no código. Interessante o sqlite4java, vou estudar a chance de coloca-lo nesse meu projeto, mas futuramente concerteza  posso estar utilizando em outro projeto. Obrigado Bruno