# Guardar imagens do servidor na minha aplicação

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação que depois de instalada, a primeira vez que é inicializada ela vai ao servidor buscar todas as imagens necessárias para o utilizador poder usar a aplicação.

Escolhi a biblioteca [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) para manipular as minhas imagens mas não sei como posso descarregar o ficheiro e a seguir salvar a imagem na minha directoria `/data/data/pt.MEU_PROJECTO/` para depois poder popular as minhas `ImageView`'s mesmo que o utilizador não tenha ligação à internet.

Tenho a seguinte função criada para salvar as minhas imagens que construí a partir de um tutorial mas não sei que parâmetro da classe Picasso devo passar nem em que directoria é que está a ser utilizada para salvar as imagens.

```
public static void saveAssetImage(Context context, String assetName){
    File fileDirectory = context.getFilesDir();
    File fileToWrite = new File(fileDirectory, assetName);

    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    try{
        InputStream in = assetManager.open(assetName);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite);

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

```
saveAssetImage(getApplicationContext(), Picasso.with(this).load(urlImagem).fetch());
```

Preciso também de saber como posso ir buscar a imagem, depois de guardada, à directoria correcta para popular as minhas `ImageView`. Encontrei este código mas houve muitos utilizadores que comentarão não estar a funcionar.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///data/data/pt.MEU_PROJECTO/file.jpg");
image.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: Talvez isso ajude http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44092/como-salvar-recuperar-imagem-na-mem%C3%B3ria-no-android

Answer (score 2):

Para salvar a imgem:

```
    Picasso.with(context).load(URL IMAGEM).into(target);

 private Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String pathImage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/PASTA ONDE ESTÁ A IMGEM";

                    File projDir = new File(dirPath);

                    if (!projDir.exists()) {
                        projDir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    File file = new File(dirPath + File.separator + "NOME DA IMAGEM");

                    try {
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            file.delete();
                        }
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                        ostream.close();

                        user.setUrlPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {
            }
        }
    };
```

Para recuperar a imagem utilize o seguinte:

```
String pathImage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/PASTA ONDE ESTÁ A IMGEM/NOME DA IMAGEM";

File f = new File(pathImage);
Picasso.with(context).load(f).into(this.mUserPhoto);
```